# CKEditor insert HTML into textarea

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'm trying to insert text into CKEditor using javascript. I have currently got this script:

```
function quote_<?php echo $row['pid']; ?>() {
        var stringContent = $(".content_<?php echo $row['pid']; ?>").html();
         $("#wysiwyg").val("[quote=<?php echo $row['author']; ?>]" + stringContent + "[/quote]");
         CKEDITOR.instances.wysiwyg.insertHtml('[quote=<?php echo $row['author']; ?>]' + stringContent + '[/quote]');
}

<textarea name="message" style="width:100%" tabindex="3" rows="10" id="wysiwyg">
</textarea>
```

HTML is not being inserted into the instance 'wysiwyg', so I can't get this to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This row:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.wysiwyg.insertHtml('[quote={$row['author']}]' + stringContent + '[/quote]');
```

the single quotes around 'author' are not escaped. Try:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.wysiwyg.insertHtml("[quote={$row['author']}]" + stringContent + "[/quote]");
```

Comment: Am facing the same issue Kindly look on this , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55298230/ckeditor-is-undefined-in-angular-6

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.TEXTATEA_ID.insertHtml('<p> html here. </p>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always embed your javascript code into a .php file, as it follows:

```
<?php

echo <<<JS

<script type='text/javascript'>
    function quote_{$row['pid']}() {
        var stringContent = $(".content_{$row['pid']}").html();
            $("#wysiwyg").val("[quote={$row['author']}]" + stringContent + "[/quote]");
        CKEDITOR.instances.wysiwyg.insertHtml('[quote={$row['author']}]' + stringContent + '[/quote]');
}
</script>
    <textarea name="message" style="width:100%" tabindex="3" rows="10" id="wysiwyg">
    </textarea>
JS;
?>
```

Also, you can alternatively use php files in which you keep pure (X)HTML markup, but when you come to the point where you would normally echo, just do that:

```
var stringContent = $(".content_"+<?= $row['pid']; ?>).html();
```

Comment: I can presume you already know all this, but you should be more careful about some shady syntax mixes, because javascript has the mighty power of silently failing, and that's exactly the point where you wouldn't know what happened actually ;-)